# Finding a particular attribute's value from a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, modelattribute

I'm trying to find the value of a particular model's attribute in rails. Here's what my code in the User controller's 'create' method looks like:

```
@user = User.find(1, :select => :money)
existing_money = @user
puts "#{existing_money}"
```

In my Heroku logs I'll see a variant of the following output instead of the :money integer for that particular user (with :id 1)

```
#<User:0x00000004e7cbc0>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As existing_money is just the object you are seeing the object's ID.
As you want the money attribute you have to reference that too.

```
puts "#{existing_money.money}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@user = User.find(1, :select => :money)
```

You are setting the `@user` instance variable with an object that has only one value, namely the `money` value. For now, all this does is save you a few bytes, by leaving off things like `id`, `email`, and any other columns you have in that table. It does however still return an object with attributes, the only difference is your object has only one attribute to call.

```
existing_money = @user
```

Given that `@user` is still an object with a single attribute, you now save this object in the `existing_money` local variable. What you probably want to do is *only store the `money` attribute in this variable`.

So you'd need this:

```
existing_money = @user.money

puts "#{existing_money}"
```

After the above change, this `puts` statement should return the attribute value, not the object encapsulating the attribute.